# Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type ICacheManager

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine, commerce-server, commerce-connect

I have a sitecore commerce site in my local machine and when I click the 'Book Now' button on the website, it shows this error message:

> GetCurrentCart: Activation error occured while trying to get instance
>   of type ICacheManager, key "Sitecore_CommerceCartCache"

[image]

The commerceengine site which is in the same machine is also up.
I tried restarting IIS but no luck.

These are the registered logs:

> ERROR Commerce Server:  Error retrieving the Cache
>   Manager.  Message: Activation error occured while trying to get
>   instance of type ICacheManager, key "Sitecore_CommerceCartCache" 15084
>   13:05:52 ERROR GetCurrentCart failed Exception:
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException Message:
>   Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type
>   ICacheManager, key "Sitecore_CommerceCartCache" Source:
>   Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer    at
>   Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Caching.EnterpriseLibraryCacheProvider.GetCache(String
>   prefix, String cacheName, String& actualCacheName)    at
>   Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Caching.EnterpriseLibraryCacheProvider.GetData[T](String
>   prefix, String cacheName, String cacheKey)    at
>   Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Website.Util.CartCacheHelper.GetCart(String
>   customerId) in D:\Projects\External\DC
>   Ecomm\sitecore.demo.retail\src\Foundation\Commerce\Website\Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Website\Util\CartCacheHelper.cs:line
>   65    at
>   Sitecore.Feature.Commerce.Orders.Website.Controllers.CartController.GetCurrentCart()
>   in D:\Projects\External\DC
>   Ecomm\sitecore.demo.retail\src\Feature\Orders\Website\Sitecore.Feature.Commerce.Orders.Website\Controllers\CartController.cs:line
>   139
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException
>   Message: Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.ICacheManager", name =
>   "Sitecore_CommerceCartCache". Exception occurred while: while
>   resolving. Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.ICacheManager, is an
>   interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
>   ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.ICacheManager,Sitecore_CommerceCartCache
>
> Source: Microsoft.Practices.Unity    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object
>   existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name,
>   ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message: The current type,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.ICacheManager, is an
>   interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
>   Source: Microsoft.Practices.Unity    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForAttemptingToConstructInterface(IBuilderContext
>   context)    at
>   BuildUp_Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.ICacheManager(IBuilderContext
>   )    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)    at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type
>   t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
>
> 1584 13:05:53 ERROR Commerce Server:  Error retrieving the Cache
>   Manager.  Message: Activation error occured while trying to get
>   instance of type ICacheManager, key "Sitecore_CommerceCartCache" 1584
>   13:05:53 ERROR GetCurrentCart failed Exception:
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException Message:
>   Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type
>   ICacheManager, key "Sitecore_CommerceCartCache" Source:
>   Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer    at
>   Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Caching.EnterpriseLibraryCacheProvider.GetCache(String
>   prefix, String cacheName, String& actualCacheName)    at
>   Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Caching.EnterpriseLibraryCacheProvider.GetData[T](String
>   prefix, String cacheName, String cacheKey)    at
>   Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Website.Util.CartCacheHelper.GetCart(String
>   customerId) in D:\Projects\External\DC
>   Ecomm\sitecore.demo.retail\src\Foundation\Commerce\Website\Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Website\Util\CartCacheHelper.cs:line
>   65    at
>   Sitecore.Feature.Commerce.Orders.Website.Controllers.CartController.GetCurrentCart()
>   in D:\Projects\External\DC
>   Ecomm\sitecore.demo.retail\src\Feature\Orders\Website\Sitecore.Feature.Commerce.Orders.Website\Controllers\CartController.cs:line
>   139
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException
>   Message: Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.ICacheManager", name =
>   "Sitecore_CommerceCartCache". Exception occurred while: while
>   resolving. Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type,
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.ICacheManager, is an
>   interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Answer (score 3):

probably it is too late to answer this, but as a reference for other which encountered the same problem. After installation i have got the same error, the reason for me was, i forgot to merge the merge configs to the web.config as mentioned here:

1. Go to the Website folder and open the web.config file.
2. Navigate to the \Website\MergeFiles folder.

   - Merge the contents of the Merge.CommerceServer.config file into the web.config file.
   - Merge the contents of Merge.Commerce.Storefront.config file into the web.config file.
3. Save your changes to the web.config file.

Hope it helps others.

Comment: It's never too late to answer :-)